# Odoo - Add (AM/PM) in datetime in qweb report

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

```
<span t-field="o.date_order"/>
```

which gives output as:

04/11/2017 09:48:35

But how can I get output like:

04/11/2017 09:48 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<span t-field="o.date_order" t-field-options='{"format": "MM dd y h:mm a"}'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Aiswarya,**

**Try this below code,**

### **1. Using Template,**

If your `o.date_order` field return this format type `10/10/2017 10:10 AM` DateTime with AM/PM so use below code otherwise gives the error.

```
<td>
    Order Date:
    <t t-esc="time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %a',time.strptime(o.date_order,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %a'))" />
</td>
```

### **2. You can also be using create function in python,**

If you have multiple date fields use same or different date format so python function use is better because improve Reusability of code.

**1. First your report.py file inside write below code,**

```
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):  
    super(class_name, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)  

    self.localcontext.update({  
        'format_date':self.format_date  
    }) 

def format_date(self,date):
        if date:
           return str(datetime.strptime(o.date_order, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %a').strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %a'))
```

**2. Second your report_view_template.xml file inside write below code,**

```
<td>
    Order Date:
    <t t-esc="format_date(o.date_order)" />
</td>
```

I hope my answer is helpful. If any query so comments, please.